# running out of memory while using pandas read_csv with chunksize option provided

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a large (~24GB) CSV using pandas read_csv.
This is what I do:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
sum = 0
start = time.time()
for chunk in pd.read_csv('large_iris.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=100):
    sum=sum+chunk.species.count()
end = time.time()
```

I get an out of memory error as follows:

```
python(5741,0x7fffc81cc3c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071629176832) failed (error code=3)
```

*** error: can't allocate region

I have tried to experiment with several values of chunksize ranging from 100 to 1000000. The problem persists regardless of chunk size.

Am I misunderstanding something about how read_csv works with chunksize. I understand that iterating the data with a reasonably small chunksize should resolve the out of memory issue I am seeing.
I found other posts suggesting the use of chunksize to resolve out of memory issues. But I am unable to find a post regarding out of memory issue when a valid chunksize is provided.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue was a corrupted CSV file.
While iterating "large_iris.csv" row by row, a certain row was being interpreted as being abnormally large leading to an out of memory issue.
The code snippet above works well on other well formed CSV files.